# Not able to link scm with the integration branch on sonarqube

Tags: github, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to link scm with every project present on our sonarqube. When i try to execute below command to attach scm link with the created project on the sonar

/usr/local/Cellar/sonar-scanner/4.6.2.2472_1/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.sources=././vendor -Dsonar.login=adfafdsafasweq3e -Dsonar.host.url=https://abc.xyz.net -Dsonar.links.scm=https://git.com/abc/sonarqube-example-python.git -Dsonar.projectName=xyz:xyz -Dsonar.projectKey=Sonarqube:Python:integration -Dsonar.branch.name=integration -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dsonar.c.file.suffixes=- -Dsonar.cpp.file.suffixes=- -Dsonar.objc.file.suffixes=-

scm link does not get attached to the project, but when i change the branch to ‘master’ the scm link get attached to the project on sonar.
/usr/local/Cellar/sonar-scanner/4.6.2.2472_1/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.sources=././vendor -Dsonar.login=adfafdsafasweq3e -Dsonar.host.url=https://abc.xyz.net -Dsonar.links.scm=https://git.com/abc/sonarqube-example-python.git -Dsonar.projectName=xyz:xyz -Dsonar.projectKey=Sonarqube:Python:integration -Dsonar.branch.name=master -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dsonar.c.file.suffixes=- -Dsonar.cpp.file.suffixes=- -Dsonar.objc.file.suffixes=-

Is there any way to attach scm link with sonarqube project for integration branch?